# What can be deleted from facebook user profile using the graph api?

Tags: facebook, graph, profile

Just got a shock that an app cannot delete a picture from a user profile even after getting proper permissions and valid access token. I was wondering what objects/actions can be deleted from a user profile using graph API?

Answer (score 1):

The deletable connections on a User object are listed in the documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Photos are not listed as being something that an app can delete.